# [VS2019/2022]How exactly {ServicePort} in the Docker-Compose project works and can be configured?

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-compose, visual-studio-2022

How to use other service in the Docker-Compose to be paired with the {ServicePort}? I only want a web-server(like Nginx) service to be exposed. How can I point {ServicePort} to the web-server service? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your project Properties/launchSettings.json, to use port **1234**, if you specify sslport it will become the value of {ServicePort}

"Docker": {
"commandName": "Docker",
"launchBrowser": true,
"launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
**"sslPort": 1234,**
"httpPort": 1235,
"useSSL": true
}